# Better way of expressing without using ”のための”？

Tags: usage

Last time I noticed that I am misusing the phrase "ため". For example in next phrase:

> 管理職｛かんりしょく｝のための雇用契約書｛こようけいやくしょ｝

Do you think I could say it better? For example using "向け" or "用" as in next example?

> 管理職｛かんりしょく｝向け｛むけ｝雇用契約書
>
> 管理職｛かんりしょく｝用｛よう｝雇用契約書

Thank you in advance for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These three phrases roughly mean the same thing, but のための looks less formal and it does not usually form a set phrase. 向け sounds more formal, and 用 appears commonly in a serious technical set phrase.

For example, there is nothing wrong if you say 管理職​のための​雇用契約書があれば送ってください in a business email. But if you are instructed to download it from an internal webpage, the link would probably say "管理職​用​雇用契約書", "雇用契約書(管理職用)", etc., because these would look more like one phrase as a whole.

On the other hand, [a book like this](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B007U5P0IU/) does not usually use 用 because the title is intended to look more like a friendly, ordinary sentence that contains both kana and kanji. Using 用 would look too stiff.

Answer (score 3):

> ​管理職{かんりしょく}​のための​雇用契約書{こようけいやくしょ}

Actually, this is one of the normal expressions.
I guess that you take the word "ため" only as positive meaning, and you understand "管理職のための雇用契約書" as "管理職の利益ための雇用契約書," don't you?

However, "のため" of "管理職のための雇用契約書" means just "for."
"管理職のための雇用契約書" describes both of rights and responsibirities for "管理職."

The followings are normal.

> 1) ​管理職{かんりしょく}​のための​雇用契約書{こようけいやくしょ}
>   2) 管理職向け雇用契約書
>   3) 管理職用雇用契約書
>   4) 管理職雇用契約書（In this expression, "のための," "向け" or "用" is ommitted.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations!! Thank you, your help is great...
Oh no, formally I used "ため" in the meaning of "for".

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer there.

Don't use 向け in this situation though, since it's more about being "geared towards" rather than "for".

You could also completely do without it and just go straight forward with 「管理職雇用契約書」.

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be appreciated.